# How to wait until NSURLResponse is processed to iterate through loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nsurlrequest

I am trying to process the data for each request before the subsequent request is made. There are two methods here, and the second method is called from within the first method using dispatch_semaphore to ensure the request is completed, however, this will not wait until the response has actually been received/processed it appears. This causes the chart that is being made to not be made in the correct order, and sometimes the folder names will show up for the wrong data.

```
- (void)load:(NSData*)data completionHandler:(void(^)(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error))handler

{
    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Loading... %@", s);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]; //allows for SSL connections

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setHTTPBody:data];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]

                           completionHandler:handler];

    [urlConnection start]; //start connection after request
}

//issue is occurring within this method
- (void)GetPOActivity:(NSString*)aliasname completionhandler:(void (^)(NSDictionary *, NSError *))handler;
{
    NSMutableDictionary *d = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [d setValue:interface forKey:@"interface"];

    [d setValue:@"GetDocsPerDay" forKey:@"method"];

    NSMutableDictionary *p = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    NSString *cno = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"cno"];

    [p setValue:aliasname forKey:@"aliasname"];

    [d setValue:p forKey:@"parameters"];

    NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:d options:0 error:nil];

    [self load:data completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"done");

        NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"GetDocsPerDay RAW response = %@", s);

        //checks if data is null or server unavailable
        if (apiConditions)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                           ^{
                               [hud hide:YES];
                               NSLog(@"data is NIL");
                           });
            [hud hide:YES];

        }
        else
        {
            //get values
            NSDictionary *d = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
            handler(d, error);
            NSMutableString *partnerString = d[@"Value"];
            NSArray *trArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
            NSDictionary *trDict;
            trArray = partnerString;
            NSInteger arrayCount;

            arrayCount = trArray.count;

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++)
            {
                trDict = trArray[i];
                //NSString *aliasNameString;
                //aliasNameString = test[@"AliasName"];


                if (d[@"Value"][i][@"folder"]!=nil)[folders addObject:d[@"Value"][i][@"folder"]];
                NSLog(@"folder is %d %@",i,d[@"Value"][i][@"folder"]);

                NSLog(@"%d",i);

            }

            dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(folders.count);

            int i = 0;

            for (NSString *folder in folders)
            {
                NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

                NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

                NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

                [components setWeek:-1];

                NSDate *lastweek = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:date options:0];

                NSLog(@"%@", lastweek);

                NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                formatter.dateFormat = @"MM-dd-yyyy";
                NSString *today = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
                NSString *prevWeek = [formatter stringFromDate:lastweek];

                [self GetPOActivity2:aliasname startdate:prevWeek enddate:today document:folder completionhandler:^(NSDictionary *dictionary, NSError *error) {
                    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
                    if (i == folders.count-1)
                    {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                                       ^{
                                           //[hud hide:YES];
                                           [self initFakeData];
                                       });
                    }


                }];

                i++;
                dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
            }

            [hud hide:YES];

        }//end of else statement

    }];//end of block
}

 //final method called within loop
- (void)GetPOActivity2:(NSString*)aliasname startdate:(NSString*)startdate enddate:(NSString*)enddate document:(NSString*)document completionhandler:(void (^)(NSDictionary *, NSError *))handler;
{
    NSMutableDictionary *d = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [d setValue:interface forKey:@"interface"];

    [d setValue:@"GetDocsPerDay2" forKey:@"method"];

    NSMutableDictionary *p = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [p setValue:aliasname forKey:@"aliasname"];
    [p setValue:startdate forKey:@"startdate"];
    [p setValue:enddate forKey:@"enddate"];
    [p setValue:document forKey:@"document"];

    [d setValue:p forKey:@"parameters"];

    NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:d options:0 error:nil];

    [self load:data completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"done");

        NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"GetDocsPerDay2 RAW response = %@", s);

        //checks if data is null or server unavailable
        if (apiConditions)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                           ^{
                               [hud hide:YES];
                               NSLog(@"data is NIL");
                           });
            [hud hide:YES];

        }
        else
        {
            //get values
            NSDictionary *d = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
            handler(d, error);
            NSMutableString *partnerString = d[@"Value"];
            NSArray *trArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
            NSDictionary *trDict;
            trArray = partnerString;
            NSInteger arrayCount;

            arrayCount = trArray.count;

            JBdataCount = arrayCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++)
            {
                trDict = trArray[i];

                if (d[@"Value"][i][@"data"]!=nil)
                {
                    [dataArray addObject:d[@"Value"][i][@"data"]];

                    NSString *tempMonth = @""; //used for month name
                    tempMonth = [self convertMonthToString:d[@"Value"][i][@"month"]];

                    [dateArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@ %@",tempMonth,d[@"Value"][i][@"day"],d[@"Value"][i][@"year"]]];
                }
                NSLog(@"data is %d %@",i,d[@"Value"][i][@"data"]);
                NSLog(@"%d",i);

            }
            [hud hide:YES];

        }//end of else statement

    }];//end of block
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, the best solution here is to use something like [PromiseKit](http://promisekit.org).